# get the last character from a string after a character in SharePoint Calculated Column

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

ROY-AMD-BOL-727

I am trying to extract the last letters after the character "-".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this formula.

=RIGHT([test],LEN([test])-FIND("-",[test],FIND("-",[test],FIND("-",[test])+1)+1))

Result:

[image]